# Django custom field: 'module' object has no attribute 'NameOfCustomField'

Tags: python, django

I need help using a custom field called CustomModelChoiceField in a Django form. I'm trying to just override ModelChoiceField's `label_from_instance` method

My form:

```
from django import forms
from myfolder.otherfolder.fields import CustomModelChoiceField

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    # I had to override init to get some paramaters, so I'll simplify it
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #skipped querying code
        self.fields['custom'] = CustomModelChoiceField(queryset = custom_dates,
                                                      required = False,
                                                      widget = forms.Select(attrs={"onChange":'changeCalendar()'}),
                                                      label = "Choose a date")
```

My custom fields.py file (which is in the same folder as forms.py, and the import statement worked). Taken from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield):

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField
class CustomModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, custom_date):
        return str(custom_date.end_date)
```

Then when I try to view the page, I get:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'CustomModelChoiceField'
```

It could be that my fields.py is in the wrong folder or that I suck at subclassing. Any ideas?

Comment: Should it be from <name of app directory>.fields import CustomModelChoiceField ?

Comment: if you use `from foo import name_that_doesnt_exist_in_foo` the error is `ImportError: cannot import name 'foo'`, you would only get the `AttributeError` if you instead just did `import fields` and then used `fields. CustomModelChoiceField` so I invite you to share with us the code that actually raises the error you are getting.

Comment: Yes it should be`'from myfolder.myotherfolder.fields import CustomModelChoiceField` . I'm legally not allowed to tell you the names, but I definitely should have put in placeholders.

Comment: Actually, that was the problem. And there is an old fields.py in the root directory of my project that I forgot to delete from earlier attempts. That's why I didn't get an ImportError and why my IDE didn't catch it.